# One-liner for setting different modifiers to get / set

Tags: c#, getter-setter, access-modifiers

Here's how I do it now:

```
protected bool __myMember = true;
bool myMember { public get { return __myMember; } protected set { __myMember = value; } }
```

Here's how I'd ideally want to do it (or something very similar):

```
public-get protected-set bool myMember = true;
```

Is this possible? Or is there any other way to shorten how I currently do it? Should I **not** be doing this?

Maybe a solution would be if we could create modifiers in csharp... But I doubt we can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply

```
public bool myMember { get; protected set; }
```

no need to add the backing field.

In reality the backing field is still there. It is only hidden and handled directly by the compiler as this little piece of IL demonstrates

```
void Main()
{
    myTest t = new myTest();
    Console.WriteLine(t.member);
}

class myTest
{
    public bool member {get; protected set;}
}


IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+myTest..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // t
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // t
IL_0007:  callvirt    UserQuery+myTest.get_member
IL_000C:  call        System.Console.WriteLine

myTest.get_member:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+myTest.<member>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  ret         

myTest.set_member:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+myTest.<member>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ret         

myTest..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

Comment: **D'oh**, perfect! I actually knew (about `{ get; set;}` and have forgotten / subconsciously ignored I could investigate it and expand on it as such. :P Only **issue** here: **can't initialize** with this.

Comment: According to the [C# Default Values Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx) the default value for a boolean is false

Comment: Yes, but what about to strings or different types to which I want to actually set a value?

Comment: I think that's the reason for the existance of backing fields and the more verbose approach. By the way, the simplified method is only a system to hide the presence of the backing field that is handled directly by the compiler

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was a sugar syntax. Oh well... It does mostly answer the question... I was fearing it wasn't even possible to get any close. Thanks! :D

Comment: Don't forget that you can always initialise properties in a constructor. In reality when you have self initialising fields the IL generated runs the code in the constructor